# C# StringWriter is faster than C++ ofstream (via pinvoke)?

Tags: c#, performance, visual-c++, dll, pinvoke

I'm just a beginner at c++ so I might be doing something wrong but anyways I created a c++ dll and I call it from my wpf project:

c++ code:

```
extern "C" __declspec (dllexport) double writeTxt()
{   
    ofstream mf("c:\\cpp.txt");     
    for(int i=0;i<999;i++)
    {
     mf<<"xLine: \n";
    }
    mf.close();
    return 1;

}
```

calling code from c#:

```
[DllImport(@"C:\Users\neo\Documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestDll\Debug\TestDll.dll",
       CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
    public static extern double writeTxt();
```

Now I'm trying to compare the execution time with this c# function:

```
double writeTxtCs()
    {
        StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(@"c:\cs.txt");
        for (int i = 0; i < 999; i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine("Line: " + i);
        }
        sw.Close();
        return 0;
    }
```

but the c# function is about twice as faster than the c++ function.
tested like this:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        long[] arr = new long[100];
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
        {
            sw.Start();
            //double xxx = writeTxt();
            double xxx = writeTxtCs();
            arr[i] = sw.ElapsedMilliseconds;
            sw.Reset();
        }
        MessageBox.Show(arr.Average().ToString());
        Close();
    }
```

When running the c# function I normally get ~0.65ms and when running the c++ function I get ~1.1ms.
my question is: am I doing something wrong or does c# really is faster in this scenario than c++?

Comment: have you tried running maybe 1000 times more tests than 100 at a time, to get a better idea? Maybe go for about 100k iterations, minimum.

Comment: I agree that the benchmark is not adequate; actually, it is a very poor microbenchmark. In any case, note the when writing to IO, buffering is often of great importance (perhaps more so than raw CPU speed).

Comment: Since you mentioned you were a beginner, I would suggest that until you have an actual problem with performance, [do not do any pre-optimization as it will most likely be a waste of time](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html).

Comment: @Erik the whole purpose of this project is to learn c++, it isn't a part of a real project.

Comment: So you're asking a question stated in the [FAQ What kind of question should I not ask here - You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All other answers have valid points. In addition to those:

You are testing against "Debug" build of your C++ DLL and that might be degrading C++ performance more than how it affects C#'s performance. Try unleashing optimizations on both and see how it works out for you.

Nevertheless I/O doesn't have much to do with the "language". It's more about runtime and the OS.

Comment: Well changing both projects to release mode made the difference.
I'll keep on testing it but now the c++ function is 10 times faster than the c# function.

Answer (score 4):

You're not testing C++ vs. C#. You're testing [C++ plus libraries] vs. [C# plus libraries].

In order to find out why ofstream is slower than StreamWriter you'd need to profile the code or look into the internals.

Anyway, single milliseconds are a very small amount of time for a computer. I'd repeat the test with 1000 times the load to make timing jitter irrelevant.

Comment: I tried to increase the for loop that calls the functions by 10 but the difference is just getting bigger.

Comment: The difference getting bigger means that your old benchmark was wrong. The difference should stay the same. Try increasing the load even more. Go into the seconds range.

Answer (score 2):

It could be a buffering issue, i.e. the C# and C++ file writing guts might be buffering data in a different way, which would result in performance differences.

I recommend you use an operation which is purely CPU bound for benchmarking, rather than something IO bound (such as writing to a hard drive).  For instance, see how fast each function can count from 0 to MAX_INT.

Comment: Benchmarking languages like that is crap. You can't use the result for anything. It is purely artificial.

Comment: mixed arithmetic plus conditionals then.

Comment: There is not one score per language. There is one score per language and per workload. You need to choose a set of representative loads. That is hard.

Answer (score 2):

That's not really a reliable benchmark. You're doing file IO there, which is highly dependent on the implementation of ofstream and StreamWriter. Also, is it a problem?